# Copy-BlobFromAzureStorage

Tags: azure, azure-automation

I'm trying to copy-Blob from azure storage for that i have taken a runbook from the Azure runbook gallery named "Copy-BlobFromAzureStorage". When i try to test, it prompt me for "PATHTOPLACEBLOB" here i have given the default location "c:/" . and its running fine.But the thing is I don't understand where exactly i can find the stored blob, and it is given " PSComputerName" as "localhost". Can any one please suggest me regarding this.

**Code:**

```
workflow Copy-BlobFromAzureStorage{

param

(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$True)] 
    [String] 
    $AzureSubscriptionName, 

    [parameter(Mandatory=$True)] 
    [PSCredential] 
    $AzureOrgIdCredential, 

    [parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [String]
    $StorageAccountName,

    [parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [String]
    $ContainerName,

    [parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [String]
    $BlobName,

    [parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
    [String]
    $PathToPlaceBlob = "C:\"
)

$Null = Add-AzureAccount -Credential $AzureOrgIdCredential 
$Null = Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $AzureSubscriptionName

Write-Verbose "Downloading $BlobName from Azure Blob Storage to $PathToPlaceBlob"

Set-AzureSubscription `
    -SubscriptionName $AzureSubscriptionName `
    -CurrentStorageAccount $StorageAccountName

$blob = 
    Get-AzureStorageBlobContent `
        -Blob $BlobName `
        -Container $ContainerName `
        -Destination $PathToPlaceBlob `
        -Force

try {
    Get-Item -Path "$PathToPlaceBlob\$BlobName" -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch {
    Get-Item -Path $PathToPlaceBlob
}}
```

[image]

Comment: Please share the code so that it can be understood better how you are doing ?

Comment: please do find above code.....@Aatif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blob is placed on the sandbox where the Azure Automation runbook is running. There's not much point in putting it there, since this sandbox will be cleaned up after the runbook job finishes, but it can make sense, depending on your scenario, as an intermediary point to put the blob, such as to edit it or transfer it to somewhere else outside of the sandbox (ex another Azure Storage account or an FTP server).

Comment: can we see that blob which is placed on the sandbox. If the sandbox is cleaned up after the runbook job is finished,then where that copy of the blob will be maintained @Joe

Comment: See visually? No, Azure Automation only provides the ability to run PowerShell in sandboxes, not remote into them. The blob copy is not maintained, it is destroyed when the sandbox is destroyed. As I said, you need to move it from the sandbox to somewhere else, if you want to maintain it after download to the sandbox. What goal are you trying to achieve?

Comment: In the output pane (screen shot above), PSComputerName as localhost  and the directory:C:\  it is specified. it means that the blob is stored inside C:\ directory of a computer. This is what i'm trying to find out. To which localhost it refers? Is it referring to my PC  or the one inside azure?

Comment: The one inside Azure. "localhost" in PowerShell means the host running the PowerShell, which in this case is the sandbox in Azure. Unless you run the runbook on a hybrid runbook worker instead, of course.